# Can you edit ONLY a revision's description (not content)?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revision-history

When trying to edit the description for a revision of one of my questions on Stack Overflow (because I had forgot to input the description when I made the revision), the modification would not save unless I also edited some of the content in the question.

I did the following:

1. Clicked on 'Edited X mins ago' underneath my post.
2. Clicked 'edit' on my most recent revision.
3. Typed in a new summary in the 'Edit Summary' field.
4. Clicked 'Save Edits'.

When I clicked on 'Edited X mins ago' after that, my last revision still had the same description. I tried a few more times without success. Only when I made a small change in the revision's content did the changes to the revision's description save.

Is this behavior designed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. I always found deeply ironic (not to say humbling) that I would sometimes end up with an incorrect description on an edit that fixes spelling or grammar. Maybe that irony being maintained can be considered as a feature.

Comment: It’s designed to do that, yes. Just badly designed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this behavior designed?

Yes, that's exactly how it's supposed to work. The edit summary is not saved if there's no edit to save. So, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: With that response in mind, should I revise this question's tags (remove 'bug', add 'status-bydesign')?

Comment: @adamr I think "status-bydesign" is a tag that's supposed to be added by mods only. Even if you could add it yourself, you're required to have one of bug/discussion/feature-request/support, so swapping the tags isn't an option.

Comment: @Dennis i.e. "no".

Comment: @adamr - Only the designers can tell you whether or not it is *actually* by design. This argument seems somewhat circular to me. You ask "Is this an oversight or by design" you get an answer saying "that's the way it is implemented and so that must be the design". An alternative design would save the edit summary if the description had changed.

Comment: Asking the obvious follow-on question: is it supposed to be possible to fix the description of a previous revision? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

If you’re still within the 5-minute grace period for correcting an edit, you can try this workaround:

1. Re-edit the post:

   - Make a minor change to the post. For example, I insert a comment (`<!-- -->`) sometimes.
   - Correct your edit summary.
   - Save your edit.
2. Then, edit the post *again*:

   - Remove the minor change you made in step 1.
   - Save your edit.

There is, of course, a small risk that your edit will get rejected because of the later change. This hasn't ever happened to me, but you should keep it in mind.

Also, I’m not sure if I’ve ever tried this on a site where I don't have the “edit questions and answers” privilege.

Comment: You should **not** try this without the edit privilege. It is a waste of reviewer's time and (in an ideal world where the suggested review queue works correctly) the edit should get rejected. NB: You have this privilege on your own posts regardless of your rep level.